# Как установить старую версию python (3.4)?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

из-за того, что не получилось установить библиотеку PyAudio, удалил python 3.7 (вычитал, что эта библиотека не поддерживается в новых версиях), но при попытках скачать python 3.4 и запуске в командной строке открывается microsoft store, который предлагает установить python 3.7 или 3.8. Что в этом случае делать? И как python 3.4 установить для анаконды в работе с jupyter notebook?

Comment: 1 - Python 3.4 нет смысла ставить, если конечно вы не собираетесь его использовать под Windows XP. 2 - можно скачать пакет PyAudio под нужную версию Python (в том числе для Python 3.7) вот здесь: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio

Comment: ERROR: PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl пробовали? Битность пакета должна совпадать с битностью интерпретатора Python.

Comment: я специально посмотрел битность

Comment: всё совпадает там